# Cocos2d-x 3.0rc not detecting touches

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In the new cocos2d-x 3.0rc I wanted to detect touch in a Layer. I have over ridden functions in my class as mentioned below.

```
virtual bool onTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void onTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void onTouchEnded(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
```

but touches are not getting detected. Any idea y is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable touches I used the below code. works perfectly in cocos2d-x 3.0 RC1

```
void class_name::onEnter()
{
    Layer::onEnter();

    // Register Touch Event
    auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(class_name::onTouchBegan, this);
    listener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(class_name::onTouchMoved, this);
    listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(class_name::onTouchEnded, this);

    dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
}
```

Comment: and onexit method like this  void GameScene::onExit()
{
    auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    
    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchBegan, this);
    dispatcher->removeEventListener(listener);
    Layer::onExit();
}   ?

Answer (score 1):

Detect Touch in Cocos2d-x 3.0

write code in (HelloWorld.h)
{

```
cocos2d::EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce *Listner;
void onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *> &touches, cocos2d::Event *event);
    void onTouchesMoved(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *> &touches, cocos2d::Event *event);
    void onTouchesEnded(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *> &touches, cocos2d::Event *event);
```

}

write code in init Method(HelloWorld.cpp)
{

```
 Listner = EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
    Listner->onTouchesBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesBegan, this);
    Listner->onTouchesMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesMoved, this);
    Listner->onTouchesEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onTouchesEnded, this);
    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(Listner, this);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
enable touch on init() Or onEnter()

this->setTouchEnabled(true);
CCDirector::sharedDirector() -> getTouchDispatcher() -> addTargetedDelegate( this, 0, true );
```

Comment: @KARTHIK this does not work now in cocos2d-x 3.0 I guess. I got a block of code which works perfectly. Check it, I have answered the question myself